# Where can I obtain corpse hearts for crafting?

Tags: dragon-age-inquisition

I would like to craft up some cleansing runes so I can carve my way through the Emprise du Lion. This requires **corpse hearts**, which apparently drop from possessed corpses. However, after murdering close to fifty corpse archers woken from the ponds of the Fallow Mire, I have yet to find a single heart.

Are corpse hearts really so rare, and I should just keep "fishing" in the Fallow Mire? Or do I need to find a different... kind... of corpse? Where can I obtain corpse hearts?

Preference will be given to answers that (a) **don't** depend on certain missions not being completed eg. *Still Waters* in Crestwood and (b) don't require DLC, since I'm on the XBox 360.

Answer (score 2):

You can buy them from the [Winter Palace Merchant](http://dragonage.wikia.com/wiki/Merchant_(Winter_Palace))

He has an infinite amount of them, so go wild

It's a rare drop from Corpse Archers, it's a better idea to just buy them instead of trying to get one to drop.

Comment: Alas this is part of some DLC unavailable on Xbox 360.

Comment: @detly Yeah, aside from trying from the corpse archers, this is the only other place you can get them.

Comment: Do you know if the corpse archers in the Fallow Mire actually *do* drop them (ie. are they special in that area to prevent farming)? Because the drop rate would have to be in the 1-2% range if it's not zero.

Comment: All I can tell you is that according to the wiki, corpse archers do drop them.

Answer (score 1):

They drop much more commonly from corpses in the western ramparts of the exalted plains. I got three with five minutes.